# Why is the Schöbel-Zhu model affine?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, affine-processes

In the Schöbel-Zhu model, the stochastic volatility process is $dv_t=\kappa(\theta-v_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$.

The characteristic function of the stock process can be found by arguing that the model is affine if we expand the set of variables to include $v^2_t$.

The argument is that applying Ito's lemma we find $dv^2_t=[2\kappa(\theta v_t - v^2_t)+\sigma^2]dt+2\sigma v_tdW_t$, which is rewritten as $dv^2_t=[2\kappa(\theta v_t - v^2_t)+\sigma^2]dt+2\sigma \sqrt{v^2_t}dW_t$.

The second equation for $dv^2_t$ is indeed affine in $v_t$ and $v^2_t$. However it seems to me that it is really equal to $dv^2_t=[2\kappa(\theta v_t - v^2_t)+\sigma^2]dt+2\sigma |v_t|dW_t$, which is not equal to the first equation since $v_t$ can become negative.

Therefore, why is the formula derived by Schöbel and Zhu correct?